# TO_NUMBER, specify the decimal separator within a query

Tags: oracle11g

You can specify the decimal separator, with the TO_NUMBER function within a query. Without having to alter the session or configure the parameter in the system.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars100','L9G999D99',
                ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
                  NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
                ') "Amount"
 FROM DUAL;
```

Try this way but it does not work

Can it be solved?

Comment: Your raw value `'-AusDollars100'` doesn't have any decimal (or group) separators. This will give you the *number* `-100`. If your raw value was `'-AusDollars1.234,56'` then you'd get back the number `-1234.56`. Which is right... so I'm not really sure what you're asking? What doesn't work?

Comment: The query with this entry AusDollars1.234,56 does not convert me to -1234.56. To work, I must use the statement beforehand (alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ".," '). And what I need is to use the conversion inside the query without using "Alter session".

Comment: [Yes it does.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97961b99c8fa02b47e45948d25c28750) You get that number back whichever session NLS setting you have. You still haven't explained what isn't working. Are you maybe talking about your client displaying it as `-1234,56` with a comma instead of a period? If so that's nothing to do with your query - which just returns a number, and it's up to your client how that is then displayed...

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the next Query                                                             
select TO_NUMBER('10,35','999G990D00','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') amount
from dual;                                                                                                         Result 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number". I need a solution, without having to use (alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ".," ') a period instead of a comma

Comment: Well, yes - the string literal doesn't match the format you supplied. If that is supposed to evaluate to 10.35 then your NLS parameter is the wrong way round, both in your `alter` and in the embedded setting - it should be `,.` if you want comma as the decimal separator, as you have it in the original question. I'm still not sure what you're really asking though...

Comment: Thanks for helping. I need to change the decimal separator from (comma) to (point) inside a "SELECT" query. I do not want to use the sentence "ALTER SESSION". It's possible?

Comment: But you are getting a *number* - that's what `to_number()` generates. As said earlier, it's up to your client or application to format that number. (Which maybe controlled by the `alter`, in some clients anyway). Do you really want a formatted string?

Answer (score 0):

The `to_number()` function returns, as the name suggests, a number data type. It's up to your client how that should be displayed; which is why `alter session` can affect that output.

Your original query generates the same number regardless of the session setting:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

SELECT TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars1.234,56','L9G999D99',
                ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
                  NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
                ') "Amount"
 FROM DUAL;

    Amount
----------
  -1234,56

alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';

SELECT TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars1.234,56','L9G999D99',
                ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
                  NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
                ') "Amount"
 FROM DUAL;

    Amount
----------
  -1234.56
```

The client displays those numbers differently, but the session setting doesn't affect how the actually query works.

You can explicitly format the result back into a string if you want to control the display without altering the session:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars1.234,56','L9G999D99',
                        ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
                          NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
                        '),'9999D99',
                'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''
                ') "Amount"
 FROM DUAL;

Amount
--------
-1234.56

alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars1.234,56','L9G999D99',
                        ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
                          NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
                        '),'9999D99',
                'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''
                ') "Amount"
 FROM DUAL;

Amount
--------
-1234.56
```

Now the session setting has no effect on the displayed value either. But, it's now a string, not a number, of course.

With your second query what you showed in a comment doesn't work:

```
select TO_NUMBER('10,35','999G990D00','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') amount from dual;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

because you have the period and comma the wrong round, but with that fixed the *display* of that number still depends on the session:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
select TO_NUMBER('10,35','999G990D00','nls_numeric_characters='',.''') amount from dual;

    AMOUNT
----------
     10,35

alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
select TO_NUMBER('10,35','999G990D00','nls_numeric_characters='',.''') amount from dual;

    AMOUNT
----------
     10.35
```

Again, you can explicitly convert back to a string:

```
select TO_CHAR(
    TO_NUMBER('10,35','999G990D00','nls_numeric_characters='',.'''),
    '999G990D00',
    'nls_numeric_characters=''.,'''
  ) amount from dual;

AMOUNT
-----------
      10.35
```

which gets the same result in with either session setting.

Or you could replace the comma with a period directly via string manipulation:

```
select REPLACE('10,35', ',', '.') amount from dual;
```

though that gets messy if you might also have group separators, as your format model suggests.